Firebase email confirmation is not working
Firebase email confirmation is not working
I have set up email sending in Firebase Auth.
The email arrives, but after clicking the generated link, the email_verified flag remains false.
Here is my code for sending the email.
    email_verify_response = requests.post(
        f'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:sendOobCode?key={FIREBASE_API_KEY}',
        json={"requestType": "VERIFY_EMAIL", "idToken": id_token}
    )
    email_verify_data = email_verify_response.json()

    if 'error' in email_verify_data:
        print("Ошибка при отправке email для подтверждения")
        return firebase_error_response(email_verify_data['error']['message'], 503)
    
    print("Email для подтверждения отправлен")

Here is the code for fetching the users (I run it after clicking the link to check the flag).
    users = []
    
    
    page = auth.list_users()

    while page:
        for user in page.users:
            
            users.append({
                "uid": user.uid,
                "email": user.email,
                "email_verified": user.email_verified,
                "display_name": user.display_name,
                "photo_url": user.photo_url,
                "last_sign_in_timestamp": user.tokens_valid_after_timestamp,
                "created_at": user.user_metadata.creation_timestamp
            })
        
        
        page = page.get_next_page()

    
    return jsonify(users), 200

What could be the problem?

Once an ID token has been minted it is immutable. So the email_verified claim will only be updated once a new ID token is minted.
In the client-side code that gets the ID token, you can force getting a new token on the user object. If you send that token to the server, the email_verified will then show the up-to-date value.

What do you mean by ID token, is this the token that is issued to the user upon authorization?
I tried to register the user, then logged him into my personal account, receiving a new id token and refresh token. Then followed the confirm account link to a page that called the refresh token method, the token was updated, but email_verify is still false ((

The ID token is what your code verifies: "idToken": id_token ¯_(ツ)_/¯ The email will only be verified for ID tokens that are minted after you've clicked the link and the web page loaded. It looks like you're minting the token before that.
